# How to get ExpressJs API CORS set up properly

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have a Single Page Application(SPA) using axios that tries to get information from a ExpressJS Api running on the same server.

In the SPA axios settings I have the following:

```
headers: {
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 'Authorization': store.getters.token,
 'user': store.getters.user
},
```

and in the API i am using the npm package cors like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const adminRouter = require('./routes/adminRoute');
// More routes

app.use('/api', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/api/user', userRouter);
// using more routes
```

This works fine when running locally, but when putting the api on a server (using a node application) I get CORS errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at mysite.com. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I can access the api directly from browser and get a response without problems (since it isn't using cross reference) but at least I know the API is running.

I have tried creating the following (before I define my routes) instead without success:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange, to allow anything you have to just write `app.use(cors())` and it should work probably now it dont work because after `app.use(cors())` you write:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

then you should try with just cors() middleware. In order to set cors properly check cors`s documentation.
 [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Hello, yes of course I tried these separately :) Ah now I see I posted a collective code with both. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this did not work was because the web hotel where I hosted my ExpressJS api had not set up their nginx web server proxy so that it could accept the OPTIONS request properly and return with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: api.site.com`

If you need more information regarding the setup of cors have a look at these links

[CORS express not working predictably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644622/cors-express-not-working-predictably)

[How do I host a web application and an API from the same server while keeping them in separate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189181/how-do-i-host-a-web-application-and-an-api-from-the-same-server-while-keeping-th)

[Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests